# How to equate the coefficients in the following equation by using Mathematica

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

I have the following equations

$$A(u)=exp \left( \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \zeta (n) u^n \right)$$

and

$$\rho (e^{Tu})=A(u) e^{Tu}$$

After expanding the both equations we get

$$A(u)=1+\left( \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} u^2-\frac{\zeta(3)}{3} u^3+... \right) +\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} u^2-\frac{\zeta(3)}{3} u^3+... \right) +...$$

$$\rho(1) + \rho(T) u+ \rho(T^2) \frac{u^2}{2}+...=A(u) \left( 1+Tu+T^2\frac{u^2}{2}+...\right)$$

By equating the coefficients of both sides we get

$$\rho(1)=1$$

$$\rho(T)=T$$

$$\rho(T^2)=T^2+\zeta(2)$$

$$\rho(T^3)=T^3+3 \zeta(2) T-2\zeta(3)$$

$$...$$

I used the following code:

```
A[u_]:=Exp[Sum[(-1)^n/n Zeta[n] u^n,{n,2,Infinity}]]
P:=ρ[Exp[T_ u_]]
Q:=Expand[A[u] Exp[T u]
CoefficientList[Q, u]
CoefficientList[P, u]
```

Then I got the following answer:

```
    {E^(EulerGamma u + T u) Gamma[1 + u]}
{E^(T_ u_ + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 2\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u_\), \(n\)]\ Zeta[n]\), \(n\)]\))}
```

But I want to get the followings as the output:
$$\rho(1)=1$$

$$\rho(T)=T$$

$$\rho(T^2)=T^2+\zeta(2)$$

$$\rho(T^3)=T^3+3 \zeta(2) T-2\zeta(3)$$

$$...$$

Comment: Try `With[{m = 4}, Exp[t u] Exp[Sum[(-1)^n Zeta[n] u^n/n, {n, 2, m}] + O[u]^(m + 1)]]` and report back.

Comment: It is strange, what's happenning with your expansion of rho. Is rho some function of the expression `exp(T*u)` or something else? If it is a function, then the formula written in the fourth line of your explanation above is absolutely wrong as well as everything written after this expression. Or, otherwise, you need to give more explanations, why it is not.